# User credentials in messages in event driven architecture with Kafka

Tags: events, apache-kafka, event-driven

My first attempt to implement a microservice architecture using events with Kafka.

I have problems finding out how can I check for user credentials in a event.

My application is simple:

1. a service that controls users with email and passwords, able to create, edit and delete them.
2. a service that sends emails from those users.

My idea is to call create an event with a json like.

```
{ 
"status":"sendEmail",
"message":{ 
    "sender":"abc@zxy.com",
    "password":"123456",
    "recipient":"jkl@asd.com",
    "content":"this is my emails body"
}
}
```

Once I create this event at the second service, how can I validate with event that the user exist in the first service? I could easily do this wiht a REST communication but I would like to find out how to communicate responses between services with events messages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to either cache all user accounts in the second service (by consuming all user topic records), or perform an external lookup upon consuming email records. Messaging and RESTful services aren't necessarily exclusive.

FWIW, at least encrypt passwords before sending over unsecured/plaintext topics